# ContextNotActiveException with CDI

Tags: java, jsf, jetty, cdi

I am trying to set up CDI (for @ConversationScoped) within an app using JSF/Primefaces and deployed on Jetty.  I am receiving this exception with (what I believe is) a very basic ConversationScoped bean.  Have combed through all relevant search results I can find and come up with nothing, so will appreciate any advice.

```
    @Named
    @ConversationScoped
    public class RegisterBean implements Serializable {
...     
        private @Inject Conversation conversation;

...     

        public String doSubmitBasicInfo() {
            conversation.begin();
            if(accountType == null)
                return null;
            if(accountType.equals("seller_account"))
                return "register_seller_1?faces-redirect=true";
            else if(accountType.equals("buyer_account"))
                return "register_buyer_1?faces-redirect=true";
            return null;
        }
...
```

The relevant portion of the JSF page is:

```
    <div style="text-align:center;" class="noBorder autoMargin">
        <p:commandButton type="submit" action="#{registerBean.doSubmitBasicInfo}"  ajax="false" value="Submit" styleClass="autoMargin"></p:commandButton>
    </div>
```

The exception is:

```
javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: Conversation Context not active when method called on conversation Conversation with id: 1
    at org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationImpl.verifyConversationContextActive(ConversationImpl.java:197)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationImpl.getLastUsed(ConversationImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.isExpired(AbstractConversationContext.java:337)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.invalidate(AbstractConversationContext.java:285)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.deactivateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:146)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.afterPhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:91)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Indeed, a basic example that should work. According to the spec, the conversation scope is active during all Servlet arequests. Maybe your Jetty instance it needs some configuration? (I've worked only with Wildfly)